# JPA unexpected behaviour with shared children entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a few doubts as to the behaviour of JPA's `CascadeType.ALL` with `@ManyToMany` associations. I have the following scenario:

There is a `@ManyToMany` association between `Employee`s and `Department`s with `CascadeType.ALL` on the `Employee` side.

If I create two employees belonging to the same department

```
Department sales = new Department("sales");
Employee alice = new Employee("alice", sales);
Employee bob = new Employee("bob", sales);
```

and then I persist them, the department is persisted as expected, due to cascading.

Then I remove `alice` and `bob`, one at a time. When I remove `alice` the `Employee` is removed but the sales department is unchanged.

But when I remove `bob` (after `alice`), the sales Department is deleted automatically.

Why is that? Why didn't it try to remove the department when I removed `alice`? I would've expected that!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that an entity can't reference nonexistent entity. So if `JPA` would work as you expect then after `Alice`'s deletion and before `Bob`'s one the latter would reference nonexistent department.

Comment: Yes, but then what is Hibernate trying to do? Does it delete the department after deleting bob because it knows no-one else is referencing it? I seriously doubt this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of `Department` may be deffered to the end of transaction, that's why you observe this behaviour if you remove both `Employee`s in the same transaction.

If you try to remove only one of `Employee`s per transaction, you should get a constrant violation error during commit (unless you have something like `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your database schema), because Hibernate really removes `Department` at this point.

Also, I don't think it's a reasonable idea to use `CascadeType.ALL` at such a relationship, since `Employee` doesn't logicaly own its `Department`, I believe you do it for illustrative purposes only.

Comment: Thanks. I'm almost certain that I am deleting alice and bob in different transactions, but I'll check tomorrow.